# how to config apache namevirtualhost with different domain and different port

Tags: apache-2.2

i config the httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8801
<VirtualHost *:8801>
  ServerName sub1.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub1.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/site1
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:8802
<VirtualHost *:8802>
  ServerName sub2.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub2.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

the service works well,but the domain sub2.domain.com:8801 can also access the first site,i do not want this. how can i fix? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put them on the same port (e.g. 8801).

Apache will do its best to match a vhost based on IP address (* in this case), port and lastly, if it needs to,  based on name. It also defaults to nearest config if it can't find a match. So when you look for sub2.domain.com:8801 it can't find an exact match based on on three criteria so picks the first one as that at least matches on IP and port. If you used the same port number for both subdomain do this would not happen.

The alternative, if you really want to keep this as two ports, is to put a dummy service on the other port for each subdomain and redirect back to main port:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8801
<VirtualHost *:8801>
  ServerName sub1.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub1.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/site1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8801>
  ServerName sub2.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub2.domain.com
  Redirect : http://sub2.domain.com:8802/
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:8802
<VirtualHost *:8802>
  ServerName sub2.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub2.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/site2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8802>
  ServerName sub1.domain.com
  ServerAlias sub1.domain.com
  Redirect / http://sub1.domain.com:8801:
</VirtualHost>
```